# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict', when writing inline for loop output to JSON file

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, code-generation

I am trying to make a program which generates a JSON file, based on the user's inputs.

The JSON file will then be used to create a python file, with a class generated using the JSON file (not shown here).

Once the inputs are submitted, you choose if you want to create a new instance in the JSON object. When you submit 'Y/y', you can create a new instance. Afterwards, if you submit 'N/n', I get the error.

```
import json

class GenerateSchema:
    rounds = 0

    # This list stores
    instances = []
    while True:
        if len(instances) == 0:
            schema_filename = input("*.json filename: ")
            class_name = input("ClassName: ")

        instance_name = input("First instance name: ")
        instance_params = input("Instance parameter(s) ENTER for 'self' only: ")
        instance_description = input("Instance description (OPTIONAL): ")

        keep_generating = input("Generate another instance? [Y/N]: ")
        if keep_generating == "Y" or keep_generating == "y":

            # Appends user inputs to 'instances' list
            instances.append([instance_name, instance_params, instance_description])
            rounds += 1
        else:
            break

    def generate_schema(self):
        with open(self.schema_filename + ".json", "w") as schema_file:  
            # Writes the JSON object to the JSON file. This line gives me the error.
            schema_file.write(json.dumps(self.return_schema()))
            schema_file.close()


    def return_schema(self):
        # Returns a JSON object based on user inputs
        return {
                {
                    "class": {
                        "name": self.class_name,
                        "instance": {
                            "name": instance[0],
                            "parameters": "self" + instance[1],
                            "description": instance[2]
                        }
                    }
                } for instance in self.instances
            }

schema_gen = GenerateSchema()
schema_gen.generate_schema()
```

If you don't understand my code, please tell me. Any help or suggestions are wanted and appreciated. (I have already looked at other questions with the same error, but they don't give me a solution).

Thank-you.

Comment: The error is the result of attempting to make a set of dictionaries. Dictionaries are unhashable as they are mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by looping through the `instances` list and creating a new nested dictionary depending on the instance's name. If you entered the same instance name twice, the second input would overwrite the first (I still need to require to have different instance names)

The JSON generated has more than 1 instance (depending on how many instances you submitted). What I did was creating a new nested dictionary for each instance using a `for loop`. The code is below:

```
import json


class GenerateSchema:
    rounds = 0
    instances = []
    while True:
        if len(instances) == 0:
            schema_filename = input("*.json filename: ")
            class_name = input("ClassName: ")

        instance_name = input("Instance name: ")
        instance_params = input("Instance parameter(s) ENTER for 'self' only: ")
        instance_description = input("Instance description (OPTIONAL): ")

        keep_generating = input("Generate another instance? [Y/N]: ")
        if keep_generating == "Y" or keep_generating == "y":
            instances.append([instance_name, instance_params, instance_description])
            rounds += 1
        elif keep_generating == "N" or keep_generating == "n":
            instances.append([instance_name, instance_params, instance_description])
            break
        else:
            print("[Y/N] please: ")

    def generate_schema(self):
        make_file = open(self.schema_filename + ".json", "w")
        make_file.write('{}')
        make_file.close()

        with open(self.schema_filename + ".json", "r+") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            data[self.class_name] = {
                "name": self.class_name,
            }

            if not self.instance_params:
                for instance in self.instances:
                    data[self.class_name][instance[0]] = {
                        "name": instance[0],
                        "parameters": "self",
                        "description": instance[2]
                    }    

            else:
                for instance in self.instances:
                    data[self.class_name][instance[0]] = {
                        "name": instance[0],
                        "parameters": "self, " + instance[1],
                        "description": instance[2]
                    } 

            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, f)
            f.truncate()
```

Thank-you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your method return_schema must return list of values to dump it into JSON.

```
def return_schema(self):
    # Returns a JSON object based on user inputs
    return [
            {
                "class": {
                    "name": self.class_name,
                    "instance": {
                        "name": instance[0],
                        "parameters": "self" + instance[1],
                        "description": instance[2]
                    }
                }
            } for instance in self.instances
    ]
```